# What data structure does Google Firebase Firestore use for it's default index

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, b-tree, inverted-index, b-tree-index

I'm curious if anyone knows, or can guess, the data structure Google's Firestore is using to index arbitrary NoSQL documents by every field. I'm looking to build something similar, making it as efficient as possible.

Some info about how their default index works:

- all fields are indexed by default, but only works for equality searches not range (<,>)
- any range searches require extra indexes
- Source: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing

It's unlikely it's a standard btree index per field because the range searches would work without adding the requirement for another index. Plus if you added a new field (easy with document storage), it would take time to build an index and collections with billions of items.

One theory: 1 big index per document. Index "field_name:value" for every field in every document. The index maps to a sorted list document IDs which contain that field/value pair. It would be able to to equality search (my merging the sorted doc-ids for every equality requirement), but not a range search. Basically an inverted index.

Any suggestion for a better ways of implementing a pattern like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clarification, single field indexes do support range/inequality queries,  composite indexes are about combining multiple field filters in a single query. See this page for more on index types:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/index-overview

Each field index is stored in it's own key range with contiguous regions assigned to a server with compute and storage scaling independently under the covers. Cloud Firestore handles indexes fairly similar to Cloud Datastore (but not 100% the same).

You can see a basic overview on my [Cloud Next conference session](https://youtu.be/0EIqacNVuAo?t=1467) from last year.

Comment: I think I understand but to confirm, the underlying bigtable "index" is stored as something like Key="builtinIndexPrefix-[kind]-[field]-[value]-[entity-key]" (no properties needed). Then for equality query you use a prefix search of "builtinIndexPrefix-[kind]-[field]-[value]-" to get sorted list of entity-key? That would work and be quite fast, but the multi-equality-query would require iterating multiple index section to find the N keys that are in each. This would be quite fast, but not technically linear with result set size. Am I missing something?

Comment: Note to prior comment, [entity-key] could have been in a property insteaf of key, either work. I'm more interested in the linearity of multi-filter query results and if I understand the data structure. Thanks!